# Изменение BackgroundImage для элемента button

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть кнопка с именем `button0`. Свойство `BackgroundImage` я задал непосредственно с помощью меню свойств в `Visual Studio` и теперь по нажатию кнопки хочу изменить это свойство.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обработать событие `Click`:

```
button0.Click += (sender, args) => { /*Один из вариантов кода ниже*/ }
```

Если Ваше изображение хранится в файле, то самый простой вариант:

```
button0.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("path/to/file")
```

Более универсально будет использовать метод `FromStream`, т. к. в этом случае Вы сможете использовать картинку, например, полученную по сети.
В cлучае загрузки из файла, код будет таким:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("path/to/file"))
{
   button0.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Также использование `FromStream` поможет, если картинка хранится в памяти, как массив байтов:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(array))
{
   button0.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button0.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"путь_к_файлу");
```

Comment: не могли бы дать чуть более развёрный комментарий к вашему решению?